# How to update the url of site in vite using pages-generated library?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vite

I am currently working on vue and Vite with an inbuilt template. This is my first time using vite. Everything looks pretty good but now the requirement is to change the existing URLs of the website from `http://localhost:3000/sidebar/layouts/profile-view` to `http://localhost:3000/profile-view`. Please guide me on what should i do to fix this.

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import * as NProgress from 'nprogress'

/**
 * routes are generated using vite-plugin-pages
 * each .vue files located in the ./src/pages are registered as a route
 * @see https://github.com/hannoeru/vite-plugin-pages
 */
import routes from 'pages-generated'
import { auth } from './firebase'

/**
 * Here is how a simple route is generated:
 * import { RouteRecordRaw } from 'vue-router'
 *
 * const routes: RouteRecordRaw = [{
 *    component: () => import('/src/pages/wizard-1.vue'),
 *    name: 'wizard-v1',
 *    path: '/wizard-v1',
 *    props: true,
 * }]
 *
 * Here is how nested routes are generated:
 * import { RouteRecordRaw } from 'vue-router'
 *
 * const routes: RouteRecordRaw = [{
 *    component: () => import('/src/pages/auth.vue'),
 *    path: '/auth',
 *    props: true,
 *    children: [
 *      {
 *        component: () => import('/src/pages/auth/login-1.vue'),
 *        name: 'auth-login-1',
 *        path: 'login-1',
 *        props: true,
 *      },
 *    ],
 * }]
 *
 * Uncomment the line below to view the generated routes
 */
// console.log(routes)

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes,
})

/**
 * Handle NProgress display on page changes
 */
router.beforeEach(async (to, from) => {
  NProgress.start()
  if (to.name == 'sidebar-info-buy-now') {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (!user) {
        router.push({ name: 'auth-login-2' })
      }
    })
  }
})
router.afterEach(() => {
  NProgress.done()
})

export default router
```

Any solution appreciated!